# Adding edomz Ad code into .js?

Tags: javascript

I have a file 1.js which encrypts links in base 64. [http://filmyfundaz.com/1.js]

This 1.js encrypts my desired domain link; for example, go to get-pg.com and then scroll down to the bottom.

You will find something like..

http://6b3790d1.linkbucks.com/url/http://filmyfundaz.com/download.php?link=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5nb29nbGUuY29tLw==

This link when clicked will open linkbucks sidebar ads and when you hit the DOWNLOAD NOW button it will go to Google.com.

I just want to add edomz popunder code into my 1.js file without losing link converting function of my 1.js file.

ad code which i want to add in this 1.js is :

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
ps_username = "myusername";
ps_website_id = mysiteID;
ps_ad_cap = 0;
ps_ad_open = 1;
ps_ad_type = 1;
ps_page_url = document.location;
-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.edomz.net/popup.js"></script>
```

Any ideas ?